# Eclipse not detecting android device

Tags: android, eclipse, device

Eclipse is not able to detect my android device even though it is connected to my computer. I had it working on my computer earlier, but my hard drive crashed so I had to reinstall/setup eclipse, and now it doesn't work. I have enabled USB debugging. I updated my USB drivers/ android devices. I tried connecting my android phone first, and then tried my tablet, but there was no change. I tried restarting the ADB server. The android project runs on the emulator, but the emulator takes so long to load and is laggy. I did a lot of research on how to fix this, but nothing is working. In my eclipse console it says, "Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.4W'."

Comment: From the dos command line, what does it say when you type adb devices. Also, what is the actual Android device you're using? What is your MinSDK? For the Intel emulation, did you turn on VT mode through the bios? Did you download haxm? And did you carefully select x86 when creating your first Intel AVD?

Comment: What version of Android is installed on your devices? What are your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` settings?

Comment: I tried typing adb devices, and it just says, "List of devices attached" with nothing listed below it. I guess my computer is just not detecting the device?

Comment: I have android version 4.0.4 installed on my device, my targetSdkVersion is 8 and my minSdkVersion is 8

Comment: What is the device model name? From which manufacturer? Can you try it with a different usb cable. Sadly, not all mini-usb cables are created equal. Can you at least get the device mounted as an external usb drive (when the usb debugging is turned off)? The first step is to get that part working, before you try debugging mode. Also, you didn't answer my questions regarding getting Intel emulation working.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you're putting forward in trying to help me, but I ended up just using a third party emulator. The emulator works extremely fast so I am happy with just using that instead of my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have root, you can try to use Wireless adb via wi-fi. for this you must install from GooglePlay app like "wireless adb" run it and connect from cmd like this:
"e:\androidSDK\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe connect 192.168.0.68:5555"

**Also i recommend you to install free third-party android emulator BlueStacks, it work very fast! faster then real device connected by usb**

Comment: BlueStacks worked great. I'll just use this rather than my phone. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For virtual device try Genymotion

For hardware 
-first check if your device is connected - adb devices //some serial number should list. If empty, you need to install proper drivers manually. 
also check in windows Device manager

Comment: It was in fact empty, which drivers need to be installed manually exactly? Is it the USB driver? Or is it my android device driver? Or is it something else?

Comment: It's device drivers. Check google for your device.
In most cases, problem is that windows automatically install some crappy driver. You should in device manager
-right click/uninstall driver
-update driver manually (pick from list,have disk, select driver location on your PC)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable USB debugging then enabled USB debugging.
Relay! Yeah it's work.